# Put a curly brace under an ellipsis in a math setting?

Tags: math-mode, braces

I have

```
$m\times n = n + n + \dots + n$
```

in my text right now, but I would like to put a curly brace under the `\dots` to emphasize that there are m,n's involved. How would I do this?

Answer (score 17):

Try to use `\overbrace` or `\underbrace` with a `_` or `^` as appropiate. Also,
I would try to put the curly brace under the whole sum. It seems clearer, in my opinion:

```
\begin{equation}
  n \times m = \underbrace{n + n + \dots + n}_{m}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `$\underset{_{\{m\} }} {\ldots}$` but you may also mean `$\ldots_{ \stackrel{\{  m \}}{}}$` . I think I generally recall the latter way being the way most frequently seen in texbooks. But changing the font in this spot *is* a little tricky. You can change the font in math mode \mathsmaller or something like that.

Either one of these work for you?